# how to connect mongodb for sails on bluemix without mLab

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, ibm-cloud

I have created the following service : 
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/MongoDB/index.html#MongoDB

Below is the code from connection.js

```
  someMongodbServer: {
        adapter: 'sails-mongo',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        // user: 'username',
        // password: 'password',
        // database: 'your_mongo_db_name_here'
  },
```

How do I make it work? Am I missing something in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure **connection.js** with your VCAP_SERVICES credentials of mongoDB experimental service:

example:

```
"credentials": {
            "hostname": "10.0.116.49",
            "host": "10.0.116.49",
            "port": 10001,
            "username": "be879069-b273-4656-b5fb-3daa5c508044",
            "password": "f268582e-0a52-42a8-9b97-66889a9cb662",
            "name": "76ea370c-8678-4c51-b3cf-a0cd722ed93a",
            "db": "db",
            "url": "mongodb://be879069-b273-4656-b5fb-3daa5c508044:f268582e-0a52-42a8-9b97-66889a9cb662@10.0.116.49:10001/db"
```

note that: the MongoDB experimental does not allow you to connect to the database from your local application. You can only use is from Bluemix environment\application.

If you need full MongoDB capabilities you can try to use the MongoDB by Compose.

for other sails configuration file I suggest to take a look here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-mongo